# How to match Ethernet Shield and PC's subnet

Tags: c, arduino, ethernet

I am new to **Ethernet Shield**. I have been trying the Ethernet examples in my Arduino IDE but none of them worked. According to one of the tutorials I have read, **PC and Ethernet shield must have the same subnet**. Now, how do I do that? I badly need help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms:
Being on the same subnet, means that the IP-address is equal, apart from the last number. I.e. The PC has IP address 192.168.0.5, the arduino has IP address 192.168.0.6.

They should be connected to the same router/switch, they should have the same netmask and gateway, but the last number of the IP address has to be different. You should also make sure that no other device on the network is using that IP address.